# Uploading Multiple Files

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I have a form where users are to upload at least three documents and up to seven.  In its current state, I have all the error checking and validation functioning.  What I want to happen is for the visitor's forms to get renamed a specified name once they are uploaded and placed into a specified directory.  My code is here:  http://pastebin.com/V5ThWe7M

I believe the issue occurs around line 456.  I believe I need to have the file name stored in a variable then use the variable to process the renaming function.  The first file gets uploaded but not the second as they are assigned the same names.  I'm trying to figure out how to use the variables that store the individual file names and then use that variable to rename the file.  I'd like to have another set of eyes check it out for me and point me in the right direction.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, the CFFILE structure is overwritten each time you upload. So any values you wish to preserve, you must save to another variable. But since you are already saving the full file names to a variable, you could easily extract their extensions using list functions. For example:

```
     <cfset nomExt = listLast(clientNominationLetter, ".")>
```

A few other observations

- Consider a more unique naming scheme for your folders than "/firstName_lastName/". Otherwise, you may end up overwriting someone's files if you receive multiple submissions under the same name, like two different "John Smith's".
- The cffile values are separated into two categories: `cffile.serverXX` and `cffile.clientXX` (ie user system). They are **not** interchangeable. So be sure you are using the correct variables and be consistent.
- `FILE` is deprecated. Use `CFFILE` or the `result` attribute instead.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  Your are correct regarding the naming scheme for the directories.  I have added the users' uuid:
fistName_lastName_uuid

Comment: I accept this answer as you were able to discuss and help me resolve most of the issues I encountered.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Adding some new code into the mix...  :)

Here's some functions, just slap these in the top of your page...

```
<cffunction name="uploadFile">
    <cfargument name="formField" hint="Form field name that holds the file to be uploaded" required="yes">
    <cfargument name="renameTo" hint="What to rename the file, ex: 01_nominationLetter" required="yes">
    <cfargument name="uploadErrorMessage" required="no" default="Error uploading file"/>
    <cfargument name="allowedExtensions" required="no" default="doc,docx,pdf,txt,rt">
    <cfargument name="extensionErrorMessage" required="no" default="Only doc, docx, pdf, txt, and rtf file formats are accepted">
    <cfset var dir = expandPath("./nominationUploads/#trim(form.fname)#_#trim(form.lname)#/")>
    <cfparam name="request.filesUploaded" default="#arrayNew(1)#">
    <cftry>
        <cffile action="upload" filefield="#arguments.formField#" nameconflict="makeunique" destination="#dir#">
        <cfcatch type="any"><cfset ArrayAppend(arrErrors, arguments.uploadErrorMessage )></cfcatch>
    </cftry>
    <cfif not listFindNoCase(arguments.allowedExtensions, cffile.ServerFileExt)>
        <cfset ArrayAppend(arrErrors, arguments.extensionErrorMessage )>
    </cfif>
    <cffile action="rename" file="#dir##cffile.serverFile#" destination="#dir##renameTo#.#cffile.ServerFileExt#">
    <cfset ArrayAppend(request.filesUploaded, dir & arguments.renameTo & "." & cffile.ServerFileExt )>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="removeFilesOnError">
    <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(request.filesUploaded)#" index="i">
        <cftry><cffile action="delete" file="#request.filesUploaded[i]#"/><cfcatch type="any"></cfcatch></cftry>
    </cfloop>
</cffunction>
```

Then in your existing validation script, get rid of all the file stuff, instead you'll only need to use those functions above, something like this :

```
<cfset uploadFile('myFileField',  'renameToThis'  )>
<cfset uploadFile('myFileField2', 'renameToThat' , 'My custom upload error!')>
<cfset uploadFile('anotherFile',  'differentName', 'Another custom upload msg!', 'doc,docx', 'This one only lets you upload word docs!')>

<cfif arrayLen( arrErrors ) >
    <cfset removeFilesOnError()>
</cfif>
```

I don't have time to test the above, but I believe it to be frighteningly close.  If you encounter an issue, let me know and I'll help you debug it out.  :)

Comment: Thank you for being the only person who has help me as I've searched for help on three message boards and two email lists.

Your solution is correct to an extent.  Using your solution, the validation does still recognize the improper file extensions.  That is, if I attempt to upload an html file, the validation states it is not the correct file format.  However, the file does still get uploaded.

Where the renaming actions were originally, the files were not uploaded if they were the incorrect file type.

This is why I wonder if storing the file as a variable would work best, but just not sure

Comment: No prob. =)  Go ahead and upload them, then just blow them all away if validation fails.  You can do a filesUploaded = ArrayNew(1) and then each time you finish with an upload add it into the array.  At the end, if validation fails, loop the array and kill em!  :)

Comment: Sorry to be dense, but could you provide psuedo code of what you mean?

Comment: I'll whip something up, give me a few mins...  :)

Comment: Updated with some custom functions to handle it, should make your code base a lot smaller too.  :D

Comment: @Nate - Personally, I never use `cfparam` inside a function. I agree with the idea of simplifying things. However, that function is trying to do *way* too much and crossing all kinds scope borders in the process ... ;)

Comment: We are talking about a function that is called between 3 to 7 times per request at most.  If you pulled it into the body it would make literally zero measurable performance difference.  Also, you realize with it being fully scoped (as is every single reference in that snip) it isn't crossing any scope borders, nor is it dangerous in any way.  :P

Comment: @Nate - Sorry, it just feels a little dirty to me :P It is trying to do too many things at once, with little gain. It is cleaner and more modular to just return the results from the function. No need to use the `request` scope like that.

Comment: You are also breaking encapsulation in several places. Not to mention using hard coded variable names, which inhibits reuse. I know it is a quick example. But I am sure you will agree none of these are best practices ;)

Comment: I'm using the request scope because CF doesn't have proper static variables (without mad hax and metadata nonsense).  In another world (like Java or AS or JS or c# or c++ etc) I would create a class to manage this and store the list of files to delete in a static class level variable.  Alas, that isn't an option, but the request scope works dandy.  :D

Comment: I really appreciate the input from both of you.  I am working on Nate's suggestion at the moment and will report back.  I do not currently use CFCs but understand they will make coding life easier and cleaner.  I have the CFWACK opened next to me and will continue to hammer this out with your help.

Comment: @Leigh - I totally agree, however, the project requires multiple documents to be uploaded and named a specific name.  As the deadline nears, I'm trying to learn the best way to complete this in time.  I appreciate the help since you and Nate have been the only ones who have reached out.

Comment: @aparker81 - Start simply. Get things working in a way that you understand first. Then improve it. Done correctly, CFC's are powerful. But if you are just learning about functions and cfc's you may want to skip it for now, and read up on structuring and best practices first.

Comment: @aparker81 - Nothing says you *have to* use cfc's. Yes, things could be simplified. But trying to tackle something totally new and unknown, while under deadline, is ... a bad idea. Start with what you have. You can always improve things as you go along. What was wrong with extracting the extension from the file name like I suggested?

Comment: @Nate - have I placed your examples in the correct places:  http://pastebin.com/tCWJ3NUf ?

Comment: @Leigh - can you please elaborate on your suggestion of extracting the file extension?  With the files being overwritten because they are getting the same name, how would I implement your suggestion?

Comment: @aparker81 - This really should be moved to chat. Unfortunately SO says you do not have the rep for that feature. Do you have tinychat access? http://tinychat.com/twbjt

Comment: @Leigh - Yes, however it continually reloads and won't stay on the room.

Comment: @aparker81 - Find something else? ;)

Comment: Thank you both for your assistance.  A more in depth chat with Leigh helped me get the files uploaded in the fashion I originally wanted.  

Could either of you describe how I would use an array to collect the files that get uploaded by error so the directories do not contain junk files?

Comment: More like this : http://pastebin.com/Nein7AQP  Are you getting errors?   I'm around for about another hour if you want to chat on IM to knock this out : AIM: NateNielsen Yahoo: nielsen_nate MSN: nnielsen@cfgod.com  (yes, i totally own that domain, have for over a decade - been doing CF quite a while lol =P)

Comment: @parker81 - Very simple. Create an array. Each time a file is uploaded append the path ie `<cfset arrayAppend(yourArray, yourFilePathHere)>`. When you check for errors at the end of your process, if any are found, loop though your array and delete each file.

Comment: @Leigh - Thank you for your suggestion.  I have added

    <cfset ArrayAppend(
    arrFiles,
    recommendation6Result.ServerFileExt
    )>


After each file is uploaded and created an array variable:

    <cfset arrFiles = ArrayNew( 1 ) />

before all of that.  Do I now loop through the array at the end of each attempt to upload each file or just at the end of the file uploading process as a whole?

Comment: @aparker81 - You only create the array *once*, then append to that *same* array multiple times. How you structure it is up to you. But given your desire to use one array, deleting everything at once would make more sense.  BTW: SO is not really designed for long conversations. So you should probably open new (smaller) questions.

Comment: My apologies.  I guess I just have one big complicated problem.  Thank you.

Comment: @aparker81 - Just attack one small piece at a time and post small questions for each problem. S.O. is more designed for small focused questions rather than long threads detailing the evolution of an application ;-)